# The colours in my css code don't match up to the ones on my localhost server

Tags: html, css, colors, localhost

I have changed all the colours in a css template I downloaded but none of the colours actually change from the original when I open up the website on my localhost server. When I inspect the webpage on google it says in the css code the colours are the original code even though I have changed it and saved the file. Just wondered if there is a possible reason for this since when I inspect the page it says there is no errors.

When just the html document is opened without the server the correct colours are showing, but when it is opened on the local host server it has the original incorrect colours. I have changed every one of the original colours in the css file and it has made no difference. All the path files are correct and it reads the correct files.

Comment: Maybe your CSS file is being cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possibly caching the css file, if you are using google chrome, press f12 to open the devtools, go to the "Network" tab at the top and click the checkbox labelled "Disable Cache".

Comment: I've just tried this and the colour is still coming up as orange (the original colour), possibly any other reasons it could be?

Comment: You need to keep the chrome devtools open for the disable cache to work. you can also press ctrl+f5 to force refresh the page.

Comment: OMG thank you its worked! is there a way to stop it caching without devtools open?

Comment: You can use ctrl+f5 to "force refresh" which will re-aquire the cached materials. You dont need to have devtools open to do this. Happy to help! Please remember to mark this is the correct answer. :)